# How can I show that $2^x\geq x^2 \iff 2^{1/2}\geq x^{1/x}$?

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that $2^x\geq x^2 \iff 2^{1/2}\geq x^{1/x}$?

If I Substitute $x$ with $1/2$ then $2=1/x$. But I don't know why this Substitution is allowed because $x$ is a variable.

Can somebody please explain me the equivalence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't substitute anything. You raise both sides to the power of $\frac1{2x}$, and simplify. Since $\frac{1}{2x}$ is positive, this doesn't change the direction of the inequality sign.

Comment: As you have rightly pointed out, the relation holds only if $x>0$. For example, for $x=-0.5$, $2^x=0.707\geq 0.25=x^2$. However, $2^{1/2}=1.414\leq 4=x^{1/x}$.

Comment: @GeethuJoseph You get into trouble with making sense of $x^{1/x}$ and especially $\leq$ and $\geq$ if $x$ is negative. For instance, $(-0.5)^{-0.5}$ is not $4$.

Comment: Yes. My mistake. Thanks!